# Prove trigonometric identities in nasm

Tags: x86, nasm, x87

Given to prove trigonometric identity:

```
cos(fi+theta) = cos(theta)cos(fi)-sin(theta).sin(fi)
```

The following program written in NASM should print 1 when the identity is verified else 0. I always get 0 as the output. According to me, I think my logic is right. There exists some problem in the loading of memory or stack overflow.

```
[bits 32]

extern printf
extern _exit


section .data

hello: db "Value =  %d ", 10, 0
theta: dd 1.0
fi: dd 2.0
threshold: dd 1e-1
SECTION .text                   

global  main                ; "C" main program 

main:
start:


; compute cos(theta)cos(fi)-sin(theta).sin(fi)
fld dword [theta]
fcos
fld dword [fi]
fcos
fmul st0,st1
fstp dword [esp]
fld dword [theta]
fsin
fld dword [fi]
fsin
fmul st0,st1
fld dword [esp]
fmul st0,st1
fstp dword [esp] 

;compute cos(fi+theta)
fld dword [theta]
fld dword [fi]
fadd st0,st1
fcos

; compare
fld dword [esp]  
fsub st0, st1
fld dword [threshold]
fcomi st0, st1
ja .equal
mov eax, 0
jmp .exit

.equal:
    mov eax, 1
.exit:

    mov     dword[ esp ],       hello
    mov     dword [ esp + 4 ],   eax
    call   printf

    ; Call 'exit': exit( 0 );
    mov     dword[ esp ],       0
    call   _exit
```

Comment: Do you realize that [due to limitations inherent to IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf), such identities will be _very rarely_ true? Moreover, since `pi` cannot be expressed in finite precision and IEEE-754 does not require correct rounding for `sin()` and `cos()` due to the table maker's dilemma, `sin(pi)` and `cos(pi/2)` do not necessarily equate to `0`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Then how do we prove these identitites?

Comment: One does so with algebra and calculus, knowing that their implementation with IEEE-754 arithmetic will only ever be an approximation. That's also why one never tests for exact equality between floating-point values, as you do; One is usually more interested in _approximate_ equality (within a small absolute or relative delta from the true value).

Comment: See also [Bruce Dawson's article on FP comparisons](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/); that might help clear up your understanding of what floating point is for and what you can and can't usefully do with it.  Also note that testing a hypothesis for one single test-case value might disprove it, but you could only prove it using this technique by testing every possible 32bit `float` value.  There are only 2^32 of them (including NaNs), so it doesn't actually take an unreasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 3):

Testing one value doesn't prove an identity!  If I evaluate `x*x` and `x+x` for `x=2`, does that mean I've proved that `x^2 = x+x`?

Testing with all possible `float`s (2^32 of them including NaNs) is a good way to check that a function you've written works properly for all possible corner cases, but floating point numbers still aren't the same thing as mathematical real numbers.  Esp. when the results have significant errors (see below about `fsin`).

Trying something like this and finding it works for all `float`s is confirmation that it's worth looking for mathematical proof, not that you've found it.

---

Also note that on Intel CPUs (and apparently all other x86 CPUs except [AMD k5](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/#comment-16552)) **the `fsin` insn is *not* accurate for inputs near Pi**.  In the worst case, the error is [1.37 quintillion units in the last place, leaving fewer than four bits correct](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/), according to Bruce Dawson's excellent blog post.  This is due to range-reduction with only a 66 bit Pi constant, and can't be fixed for backwards-compatibility reasons.  (i.e. the exact behaviour of `fsin` is essentially part of the ISA, warts and all).

The standard add/sub/mul/div/sqrt operations all produce results with at most 0.5 ulp of error (i.e. even the last bit of the mantissa is rounded correctly).

Bruce has a whole series of FP articles, with an index in [this one about FP comparisons](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).  I've added links to some of those articles to the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, because they have such good info.  They're not all about x87; most of them mention how things are different between x87 and SSE when it matters for current versions of MSVC and/or gcc.

---

#### Fun fact: A floating point trig identity:

`sin(double(pi)) != 0.0`.  You shouldn't expect it to be, because `double` can't exactly represent the value of the irrational number pi.  However,

```
 pi ~= double(pi) + sin(double(pi))
```

(If `sin(double(pi))` is evaluated accurately, not with x87 `fsin`, and you do the addition with more precision than `double`)

Quoting Bruce Dawson again:

> This works because the sine of a number very close to pi is almost equal to the error in the estimate of pi. This is just calculus 101, and a variant of Newton’s method, but I still find it charming.

For more, [see Bruce's FP comparison article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/), and search in it for `sin(pi)`.  He has a whole section about this floating-point trig identity.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Found!**
In answer to your question, your code has one instruction wrong: I've added comments...

```
fld dword [theta]  ; Load theta
fcos               ; Get its cos()
fld dword [fi]     ; Load fi
fcos               ; Get its cos()
fmul st0,st1       ; Multiply them
fstp dword [esp]   ; Store away on stack [Why?]

fld dword [theta]  ; Load theta
fsin               ; Get its sin()
fld dword [fi]     ; Load fi
fsin               ; Get its sin()
fmul st0,st1       ; Multiply them

fld dword [esp]    ; Get what was stored away
fmul st0,st1       ; Multiply them??? [ You meant fsub!]
fstp dword [esp]   ; Store it away
```

The second-last line should be `fsub`, not `fmul`

---

**General comments:**
You've got a symbol `pi` in your code, and it is only set to `3.14` - luckily you don't use it in your code. Still, don't do this: the x87 knows all about pi: `FLDPI`

Another thing you're doing correctly is comparing against a threshold - still, `1e-1` is a pretty large delta...

You have a *much* more fundamental problem though, and you mention it when you talk about "stack overflow". Your code is storing values in the (program) stack without making room for them first:

```
fstp dword [esp]
...
fld dword [esp]
...
mov     dword[ esp ],       hello
mov     dword [ esp + 4 ],   eax
call   printf
```

This last one could crash your program: `esp+4` could be past the top of the stack! If you want to use `mov` rather than `push`, you should start your program with `sub esp,8` to make room for two `dword`s first.

And you do know that the x87 already has an internal stack of 8 floating point registers? You can 'save away' values inside that stack while working out other interim results, then get those values back again. Storing them to memory (such as the first line of code above) actually reduces the precision of your interim results.

Comment: If you're going to exit instead of `ret`urning from `main`, you actually can safely clobber some space above your initial `esp`.  argv is at `[esp+12]`, as passed by the CRT startup code that called main, and the ABI requires it to exist on the stack.  It's highly likely that there are a few more dwords above that, but you can't assume anything other than your function's return address and args.

Comment: All I can say is: **shudder**!

Comment: Overwriting your return address as scratch space sounds like a fun idea to me :P.  As long as you're not doing that as part of a big project in asm.  Hand-written asm is fun for small things, or for local optimizations (when there's no way to get the compiler to emit what you want), but not for big code where maintainability matters, and a compiler can inline more and propagate constants, etc.

Comment: There is another problem with the code, namely that it unbalances the x87 stack. There are vastly more `fld` instructions than there are pop instructions.

Comment: Well, that's true. But this is pretty clearly a beginner, so I think overwriting your return address as scratch space, and relying on exit to clean up the mess that you made in the FPU stack, are both rather bad practices to encourage. At least one needs to understand that a problem exists before he can decide to ignore it.

Comment: @CodyGray: yeah, totally agree.  Any clever asm trick requires a comment to document what's going on, and why it is in fact safe in this particular case.  Otherwise you'll come along later and say "oh, I can use this code I already wrote before", and put the same code in a different context where you can't get away with leaving out things like popping the x87 stack.  You have to know the rules well to understand when you can break them (this is part of what makes asm fun).  John's answer pointing out that bug is good.  (It's a bug if you do it without comments about what's happening)

Comment: But anyway, I was amused that you call unbalancing the x87 stack a "fundamental" problem with this code.  That's an implementation detail compared to the entire approach of trying to prove anything about mathematical real numbers using floating point.  I'm glad you already covered the implementation problems, since I wasn't interested in covering that in my answer.  :P